# MIPS Input Taking

Tags: windows, mips, pcspim

How to take input in main function in mips?

Comment: Depends on what OS you are using and what runtime libraries are available. Try providing more information.

Comment: in windows and compiling via pcspim

Answer (score 1):

It depends.  If you are going to ask for an integer it should be

```
li $v0, 5
syscall
```

If you are going to ask for a float should be

```
li $v0, 6
syscall
```

If you are going to ask for a double it should be

```
li $v0, 7
syscall
```

And if you are going to ask for an string it should be

```
li $v0, 8
syscall
```

But, if you are going to ask for an string and the input is going to take maximum number of characters, then you should use `$a1`instead of `$a0` when printing it.